# How to add Vaadin Polymer elements in Vaadin 7 application?

Tags: polymer, vaadin, vaadin7, web-component, vaadin-elements

I am trying to build a Vaadin 7 elements and it would be beneficial if I can somehow directly use the polymer elements like these ones --> 
http://vaadin.github.io/gwt-polymer-elements/demo/#paper/ButtonSample

However, there is no clear cut explanation or tutorial on how to add polymer elements in Vaadin application directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use web components on server-side there is an experimental [addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/elements-add-on) from vaadin. Here you find a [demo application](https://demo.vaadin.com/elements/)

Comment: Hi Marco,

I looked into it but it seems to not work properly with the other in-built components such as grid.

Answer (score 2):

On the [Vaadin forum page](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/11405605) suggestion is to take a look at: 
https://vaadin.com/labs-elements, https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/elements-add-on and 
https://github.com/vaadin/serverside-elements
but this is still experimental.

While we are waiting for official support you can include Vaadin Elements as stated in [Demystifying Web Components](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/demystifying-web-components) or to include Vaadin Elements as stated in [Integrating JavaScript Components and Extensions](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html) and [Using web components in plain java](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/using-web-components-in-plain-java).